# Programmatically show/hide virtual keyboard

Tags: javafx

I need to keep the virtual keyboard on screen, even if not used. 
Is there a way to force its visibility?

I tried to call **.requestFocus()** on a textfield but the keyboard raises only if the item gets focus via mouse or touch events (and disappears when it loses the focus)

I would like to change this default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this :

```
FXVK.init(textfield);
FXVK.attach(textfield);
```

The `Node` you will pass in will be the input field where you want to write using the keyboard (in this case, it's your `TextField`). In case you want to close the keyboard, just use `FXVK.detach();`